# Get protected property value of base class using reflection

Tags: c#, dictionary

I would like to know if it is possible to access the value of the ConfigurationId property which is located in the base class of the object and it's private. I have tried to do it with reflection with no luck. 
 [image]

Comment: Can you post exactly what you've tried and where it went wrong?  (code not a screenshot)

Comment: Having to bypass accessibility modifiers is often a sign of bad design. What are you trying to do and why? Is this for automated tests or something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To access ConfigurationId property i have used following code:

```
SubsetController controller = new SubsetController(new CConfigRepository(new FakeDataContextRepository()));

var myBaseClassProtectedProperty =
            controller.GetType().BaseType
                .GetProperty("CCITenderInfo", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .GetValue(controller);

var myProtectedProperty =
            CCITenderInfo.GetType()
                .GetProperty("ConfigurationId", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .GetValue(myBaseClassProtectedProperty);
```

Answer (score 10):

Assuming the following parent and child class:

```
class BaseClass
{
    private string privateField = "I'm Private";
}

class ChildClass : BaseClass
{

}
```

You can read `privateField`'s value from a `ChildClass` instance using reflection like this:

```
ChildClass childInstance = new ChildClass();
object privateFieldValue = childInstance.GetType().BaseType
    .GetField("privateField", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .GetValue(childInstance);
Console.WriteLine(privateFieldValue); // I'm Private
```

Comment: Why are you using an instance and `.GetType()` instead of the `typeof` operator? Note this makes your example, or at least that part, incompatible with abstract, generic, and static classes

Comment: @Aravol it's just an example of getting an object instance's type and base class at run-time. Of course it would be incompatible with abstract and static classes, you couldn't possibly have an instance of those :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with reflection.

However, in order to look up nonpublic members, you'll need to use the reflection overload which take [`BindingFlags`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx) parameters. In order to look up `private` members, you'll also need to access via  the `typeof` the base class, even when using `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy`. This also means you'll need to use the exact binding, however note that contradictory flags (such as using both `NonPublic` and `Public`) are valid and will return either at that point.

Be aware that the very *need* to look up nonpublic members could be considered code smell, and you should do so *very* carefully. Also be aware that nonpublic members are not guaranteed to have the same names across different versions.

Answer (score 0):

To add to this answer - you should use the Instance and NonPublic binding flags for sure, but you should also ensure that you are actually referencing *properties* and not *fields*.

E.g. if you have

`protected string Andrew;`

You will not be able to get this via `GetProperty`, no matter what binding flags you use. Why - because it is a field, and not a property...

To fix this, just change it to

`protected string Andrew {get;set;}`

and then you can use the GetProperty method.