# C# Unable to find other properties in custom validation attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core, .net-core

Trying to make my own Validation Attribute that uses a property name to find another property.

Currently, I am having problems finding the other property. It seems I am unable to find this property (or in fact any properties).

The check for `property == null` is always coming up as true.

Any ideas why I wouldn't be able to find properties?

This is the custom filter I have made

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var property = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName);

        if (property == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(string.Format(
                "Unknown property {0}",
                new[] { PropertyName }
            ));
        }

        var propertyValue = property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);

        // Just for testing purposes.
        return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);

    }
```

This is the model I am using behind my razor view.

```
public class OrganisationDetailsModel : PageModel
{

    private readonly FormStateContext _context;

    public OrganisationDetailsModel(FormStateContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    [RegularExpression(pattern: "(yes|no)")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select if you are registered on companies house")]
    public string CompanyHouseToggle { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [RequiredIf("CompanyHouseToggle")]
    public string CompanyNumber { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter your organisation name")]
    public string OrganisationName { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    [RegularExpression(pattern: "(GB)?([0-9]{9}([0-9]{3})?|[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3})", ErrorMessage = "This VAT number is not recognised")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter your vat number")]
    public string VatNumber { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }
        return RedirectToPage("ApplicantDetails");
    }
```

I appreciate the fact that the custom validation attribute doesn't really do anything at the moment but that is becuase I have become stuck on this issue.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Let's use the following code snippet to help explain what is going on here:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext ctx)
{
    var typeFullName = ctx.ObjectInstance.GetType().FullName;

    ...
}
```

In this example, you might expect `typeFullName` to be `XXX.OrganisationDetailsModel`, but **it isn't**: it's actually `System.String` (the type of the *property* you’re trying to validate). `System.String` clearly does not have a property named e.g. `CompanyHouseToggle` and so `GetProperty` rightly returns `null`.

I've not seen many cases where `[BindProperty]` has been used more than once on a `PageModel`. It's certainly possible, but it appears that each property is treated as being individual and that the `PageModel` itself is not being validated.

In order to work around this, you can just turn your individual properties into a complex type and use that instead. The docs and examples use an inline class for this, inside of the `PageModel` class. Here's an example of an updated `OrganisationDetailsModel` class:

```
public class OrganisationDetailsModel : PageModel
{
    ...

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public void OnGet() { }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return Page();

        return RedirectToPage("ApplicantDetails");
    }

    public class InputModel
    {
        [RegularExpression(pattern: "(yes|no)")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select if you are registered on companies house")]
        public string CompanyHouseToggle { get; set; }

        [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
        [RequiredIf("CompanyHouseToggle")]
        public string CompanyNumber { get; set; }

        ...
    }
}
```

This includes the following changes:

- Creation of an `InputModel` class to hold all properties.
- Removal of all other properties that have now moved into `InputModel`.
- Addition of an `Input` property of type `InputModel`, that gets bound using `[BindProperty]`.
- Removed `[BindProperty]` from the original properties that have now been moved.

The last step is to replace any usage of e.g. `CompanyNumber` with `Input.CompanyNumber` in the `PageModel`'s corresponding `.cshtml` and to ensure you use the `Input.` prefix when accessing properties within the `PageModel` class itself.

Answer (score 0):

By the doc. getProperties() only return publics.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=netframework-4.7.2

So if want to get non-public properties. Find on belows.

[Get protected property value of base class using reflections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184402/get-protected-property-value-of-base-class-using-reflections)

---

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context) {
    var property = context.ObjectType.getProperty(context.MemberName);

    // TODO

    return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

Comment: But the fields I am trying to get are publics? For example, CompanyHouseToggle is one I am trying to retrieve and this is public.

Comment: Ok. I found solution. GetType() method from validationContext is from Object class. So, you was wrong. You should use member "ObjectType" instead of GetType().